# Is there any way to retrieve the name of the deployed artifact programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm building a Spring web service, using IntelliJ (and Maven), and deploying it into a Tomcat container. When I run it locally, it deploys to the root application context. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can programmatically retrieve the name of the artifact deployed somewhere in code.

So here's what my Tomcat configuration looks like in IntelliJ:

[image]

In this example I called the service "image-service" and so it deploys "image-service:war". (Alternatively, I could have it deploy "image-service:war exploded".) I'm looking for a way to assign to a variable the literal string `image-service:war`, or at the very least `image-service`, automatically.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are those information not located within the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: What do you need the information for?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

You need the web application context path. To get it, inject the `HttpServletRequest` object into your controller and use method `getContextPath()` to retrieve it.

If the war is deployed in the root context you will get an empty string. Otherwise, you will get the context path under which the application is deployed (in your case `/image-service`).

---

Edit: Additional explanation for the suggestion from comment:

To make build-time variables (e.g. artifact name) available to your application, you can put custom entries in the manifest file using maven-war-plugin:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
     <archive>
         <manifestEntries>
             <distname>${project.build.finalName}</distname>
         </manifestEntries>
     </archive>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, you can read the artifact name from your code like this:

```
try {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.load(request.getServletContext()
          .getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
      String distName = properties.getProperty("distname");
 } catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle the exception
 }
```

Comment: This is good, thank you. But if I'm deploying to the root context path there's really no other to get it?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe to put the name of the artifact into manifest file during maven build? Then you can read it from your code